# How can you set up private nameservers when using AWS Route53 and EC2

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, domain-registrar, private

In the old days of setting up reseller accounts with shared hosting services like HostGator, it was simple to set up "Private Nameservers" by (after having pointed the DNS entries to the hosting company's DNS servers) going to the registrar and setting A records for the NS records.  My question is, can you do the same thing when you've pointed your DNS at Amazon Route53 (and are using the AWS ecosystem for hosting/servers/etc)?

This tutorial demonstrates what I'm talking about:

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/private-name-servers-setup

For GoDaddy specifically (which I'm not using, but many are familiar with): http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/setting-up-private-name-servers-with-hostgatorenom

It involves registering, NS A records, and DNS glue.  But I suspect in the case of this shared hosting, some magic was set up on the hosting company's DNS server side.  What about in the case of Route53?

In short, when doing a WHOIS lookup on my domain, I don't want the four AWS/Route53 FQDMs showing as the DNS records.  Though those ARE the DNS point, I want ns1.mydomain.com, ns2.mydomain.com, ns3.mydomain.com, and ns4.mydomain.com, respectively, to display on a WHOIS lookup.

Comment: If I'm understanding your last paragraph correctly, you will need to keep track of Amazon's name server IP addresses yourself and change your glue records every time Amazon make a change.  I don't know how often they make changes to those IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of Nov 2014 you can do this, here is how:

http://neonos.net/white-labeled-dns-name-servers-on-amazon-route-53-with-delegation-sets/

Answer (score 0):

This blog post explains a setup where you combine Route 53 with on-premise DNS using Unbound: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-dns-resolution-between-on-premises-networks-and-aws-by-using-unbound/